# localhost not connecting

Tags: apache2

I am not able to connect to localhost
it showed me the error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I removed apache2:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2*
```

And then I reinstalled it, but it still shows the same error.

Please someone help me, as I am new to Ubuntu I don't know much.

Comment: This needs more context.  Why are you connecting to localhost?  What are you testing?  What commands are you running?

Comment: I am making php pages needed to be run on localhost, thats why I am trying to connect to localhost

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cd var/
chmod 755 www
```

Check this [article](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) too.

If that doesn't work try this:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/
```

Comment: none of the commands is working.
`/usr/local/apache2/htdocs': No such file or directory

Comment: @Sabeer: `/var/www` is the canonical preconfigured location for the web root of Apache on Ubuntu/Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the permissions of your web folder

chmod 775 /var/www

You also need to set ownership of the file for your web user.

Comment: also just realize you're trying to access / folder try adding in an index document otherwise you're just accessing the root directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the filesystem to be accessable.

In apache config/virtual-host:

```
# Forbid default access to filesystem locations
<Directory />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

# Allow access to filesystem location
<Directory /path-to/whatever/dir/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

- See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory